# Llenar tabla de un PDF verticalmente usando DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

tengo una duda. Lo que quiero es llenar una tabla con 4 columnas, pero tiene que ser llenada en vertical. Llenando cada columna antes de pasar a la siguiente. Aquí les dejo igual una imagen para que se guíen.

```
1  11  21  31
2  12  22  32
3  13  23  33
4  14  24  34
5  15  25  35
6  16  26  36
7  17  27  37
8  18  28  38
9  19  29  39
10 20  30  40
```

Y así hasta el 5000. Como es en DOMPDF antes de que salte a la siguiente hoja tiene que terminar de llenarse todas las columnas de la hoja en la que esta. ¿Cómo creen que debería hacerlo? Muchas Gracias

Comment: haa eso esta facil, yo hice algo asi para la contabilidad de la empresa... tienes algo de codigo adelantado ???

Answer (score -1):

**Esta seria la logica que vamos a aplicar:**

1. Calcular el número de filas que tendrás en cada columna. En este caso, tienes 5000 filas y 4 columnas, lo que significa que cada columna deberá tener 5000/4 = 1250 filas.
2. Iniciar un bucle que itere desde 1 hasta el número total de filas (5000 en este caso) con un incremento de 1.
3. Dentro del bucle, calcular el número de columna actual utilizando el operador módulo (%). Para tu caso, puedes hacerlo como columna_actual = (fila_actual - 1) % 4.
4. Si la columna actual es igual a 0, significa que has llenado todas las columnas en la hoja actual y debes pasar a la siguiente hoja en DOMPDF. Puedes agregar el código necesario para crear una nueva página en el PDF.
5. Calcular el valor correspondiente para cada celda utilizando la fórmula valor = fila_actual + (columna_actual * 10).
6. Imprimir el valor en la celda correspondiente en la tabla.

*Ejemplo en PHP que muestra cómo puedes implementar esta lógica:*

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Crear el objeto DOMPDF
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

// Generar el contenido del PDF
$html = '<table>';

$filas_por_columna = 1250;
$total_filas = 5000;

for ($fila = 1; $fila <= $total_filas; $fila++) {
  $columna_actual = ($fila - 1) % 4;

  if ($columna_actual === 0) {
    $html .= '</table>'; // Cerrar la tabla actual
    $html .= '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'; // Agregar salto de página
    $html .= '<table>'; // Abrir una nueva tabla en la siguiente página
  }

  $valor = $fila + ($columna_actual * 10);
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $valor . '</td>';
  $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();

// Generar el PDF y guardarlo en un archivo
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('tabla_vertical.pdf', $output);
?>
```